# PHP form into mySql db. Array formatting question

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am working on a form that allows the user to duplicate groups of form inputs (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd9Ag/5/ ).

I would like to insert the data into a database with two tables: "question" (containing columns: "QID", "text") and "answer" (containing columns: "AID", "QID", "text").

When I submit the form, the information is posted like this (in this example the form has 2 questions, both having 3 answers):

---

question :

```
Array ( [0] => question 1 [1] => question 2 )
```

answer :

```
Array ( [0] => q1 answer 1 [1] => q1 answer 2 [2] => q1 answer 3 [3] => q2 answer 1 [4] => q2 answer 2 [5] => q2 answer 3 )
```

---

My question is: what is the best way to keep these questions linked to their answers when looping through the post variables to insert them into the database?

Should I script a way for the `name` of each form input group to be different?

Is there a way to group each of these input "sets" into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar in the past with a scheduling widget that allowed you to add days to a schedule, like you have answers to a question.  The way I handled it was to add in the extra lines via javascript, incrementing counters to name the fields.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="question[1]">
<input type="text" name="answer[1][1]">
```

Now you keep a counter in javascript of how many answers you have for the question, so when you add a new answer you just increment that counter.  For instance, if you start with a default of 1 answer:

```
var count = 1
//creating new answer field logic
count++;
answer_name = 'answer[' + question + '][' + count + ']';
```

Of course, it's a little more complicated than that, but hopefully you get the idea of where I'm going with this.

Then when you submit, you grab your question array and then just query the answer array to get all of the answers for that question.  Question 1's answers will be in $answers[1] as an array.

Comment: in my example i have it split into $questions and $answers arrays. so you'd say $questions = $_POST['question'], for example.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to have a final array like this, with everything in a single array so that it is easy to loop through while processing:-

```
array([0] => array([0] => question 1,
                   [1] =>array([0] => q1 answer 1, [1] => q1 answer 2)),
      [1] => array([0] => question 2, 
                   [1] => array([0])),
      ...
```

Check if having input names in this format produces the above post data array:-

```
 //Question 1
<input type="input" name="question[0][0]">

//Answers to 1
<input type="input" name="question[0][1][]">
<input type="input" name="question[0][1][]">

//Question 2
<input type="input" name="question[1][0]">

//Answer to 2
<input type="input" name="question[1][1][]">
```

I am not sure whether this will post the values as per the format I have given above. If it works and you prefer this format, generate like this in your code.

In order to keep it more readable, you can assign like this

```
 //Question 1
<input type="input" name="qa[0][question]">

//Answers to 1
<input type="input" name="qa[0][answer][]">
<input type="input" name="qa[0][answer][]">

//Question 2
<input type="input" name="qa[1][question]">

//Answer to 2
<input type="input" name="qa[1][answer][]">
```

Hope this helps